# window.XMLHttpRequest in Chrome vs FireFox

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("sendalertsdiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        location.reload();
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET","sendbdrdata.php?project=" + projectname,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

it works just fine in Chrome. It it hooked up to a click on a button. The sendbdrdata.php file contains a query that uploads data to a database. As I wrote in Chrome it works perfectlly. But in Firefox the location.reload prevents the execution of the senddbrdata.php file. If I remove the line

```
location.reload();
```

it works fine in Chrome AND Firefox but it will not reload the page and that is what I need here.

Comment: IE7, IE6...... IE5?? Are you for real? Where's Netscape? O_o

Comment: If you want to submit data to the server and then load a new page showing the result … **why are you using Ajax?!**. Just submit a form and have the server HTTP 302 redirect back to the display page.

Comment: Hmm... it would be very strange, if FF would enter the onreadystatechange event and passing your if-statements before sending the actual request. And I don't understand, why you want to reload the page at all. You could try to delay the execution of the reload. Replace the line with `window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 500);`. But that's not clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.reload();` will reload the page from the server into whatever initial  state it is delivered by the server i.e. without the newly collected data from your AJAX call. So remove the reload. The idea of AJAX is you can get data from the server WITHOUT having to reload the whole page.